# use of stringArray in C# and spliting it into 2 parts for autocomplete box

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, if-statement, autocomplete

i am making windows phone app in which i have to use autocompletebox ,and auto-complete box has limited capacity for source as per windows phone rules,
so i want my autocomplete textbox to change its source dynamically as per requirement so as to decrease load 
here is code snippet which i am trying but it does not work

```
string[] stringArray1 =    { "Aberdeen Bazar", "Bakultala", etc };
string[] stringArray2 =    { "Aberdeen Bazar", "Bakultala", etc };
```

I want somethinglike this

```
if (stringArray.Contains( txtphone.Text))
{
    //autcomplete text source
    this.txtphone.SuggestionsSource = stringArray;
}
else 
{
    //autcomplete text source2 if reqired
    this.txtphone.SuggestionsSource = stringArray2;
}
```

I just want logic on how can i divide autocomplete source into two parts 
also if can order it alphawise
i.e

```
if(txtphone .starts with letter from (a to o )
{
    //autcomplete text source
    this.txtphone.SuggestionsSource = stringArray;
}
else 
{
    //autcomplete text source2 
     this.txtphone.SuggestionsSource = stringArray2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution this is it

```
 if (txtphone.Text.StartsWith("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O"))
            {
                this.txtphone.SuggestionsSource = stringArray2;
            }
```